# Qual a melhor forma de ler um XML em PHP e inserir na Base de Dados?

Tags: php, mysql, xml, parser

Estou a ler ficheiros XML de cerca de 50M de informação (uns cem mil registos, podendo ser mais), e tenho duas classes implementadas de leitura de XML uma DOM e outra SAX.

Estou a ter um problema em termos de tempos de execução, demora me mais do que 10 minutos, o tempo de execução máximo do PHP, alterado por mim no `php.ini`.

Já li muito sobre isto e sei que o SAX é mais rápido que o DOM para ficheiros muito grande, que acho que é o caso.

**Um dos meus requisitos obrigatório é que ou é lido todo o ficheiro e colocado na Base de Dados, ou não insere NADA.**

A pergunta que fica é qual a forma mais eficaz, em termos de **TEMPO DE EXECUÇÃO**, de ler o XML e guardar na BD?

- Ir lendo TAG a TAG e inserindo na BD?
- Ler tudo para uma estrutura de dados e inserir tudo no final?
- Outra forma, qual?

Comment: Eu acho muito válida a sua pergunta, mas ela é *quase* que principalmente baseada em opiniões. Digo isso diante das opções que temos. Por exemplo, se lermos tudo primeiro e inserir no final da requisição, a fluidez será maior – esta é uma técnica bastante utilizada pela Microsoft nas últimas versões de seus softwares; por outro lado, se inserirmos item à item, **pode** ocorrer o problema de perdermos algo no caminho se não tivermos um *stash* de dados para armazenar e posteriormente commitar as informações à serem inseridas no banco de dados.

Comment: @GuilhermeOderdenge a pergunta é clara, qual é a forma mais eficaz EM TEMPO DE EXECUÇÃO.

Comment: Mas gostei da primeira parte da resposta sobre a microsoft :)

Comment: Além disso, você mencionou "[...] em termos de tempo de execução [...]": para ter segurança na hora de inserir tag à tag, você precisará de um stash. Ele exige *um pouco* de hardware, o que naturalmente minimiza a performance da técnica em questão; por outro lado, ler toda a estrutura e salvar no final, pra mim, é a **melhor** opção porque não há necessidade de stashes e é tudo ou nada: se conseguiu, salva; senão, esqueça o que foi feito. Além disso, essa metodologia exige uma – e apenas uma – requisição com o banco de dados, o que não se faz desperdiçar qualquer byte utilizado.

Comment: Acabaste de dar uma resposta tudo menos baseada em opiniões. Obrigado.

Comment: Realmente. Já estou formulando uma resposta, Jorge. =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vamos analisar as possibilidades que você mesmo deu:

> Ir lendo TAG a TAG e inserindo na BD

Nesse formato, nós teremos uma estrutura redundante – a cada tag lida, abre-se uma requisição com o banco de dados e salva isso lá.

**O bom:**

Se não conseguiu tudo ler e salvar tudo, faz-se, pelo menos, o que é possível; O problema desse "pró" é que ele vai contra a questão por você mesmo levantada:

> "[...]
>
> Um dos meus requisitos obrigatório é que ou é lido todo o ficheiro e colocado na Base de Dados, ou não insere NADA.
>
> [...]"

**O ruim:**

Se você não manter uma conexão com o banco de dados viva durante o ciclo de vida da aplicação, você terá o que eu chamei há pouco de *estrutura redundante*. Ora, a cada vez que fores salvar alguma informação, serás obrigado a requisitar conexão com a sua base – o que, tenha certeza, é um desperdício de processamento bem relevante; naturalmente, isso vai afetar diretamente o tempo de execução do seu serviço – *que é justamente o que **não** queremos*.

Considere esta técnica uma espécie de *streaming*. O seu processamento é fragmentado – se a experiência não for social, eu vejo mais que o desnecessário, eu vejo como algo *desperdiçoso*.

Além disso tudo, o conceito de "tudo ou nada" não se aplica sem um *stash* para um posterior *commit* – mesmo que você aplique isso, mantendo a conexão viva, o *stash* e o *commit* exigem um "a mais" de hardware – o que depreda mais ainda a performance que você tanto busca.

---

No outro lado do *tatami*, temos:

> Ler tudo para uma estrutura de dados e inserir tudo no final

**Entenda:**

Essa é uma técnica *muito* utilizada nas últimas versões dos softwares da Microsoft – é daí que vêm aquela falácia de que o Windows Phone é fluído, por exemplo: o carregamento é todo feito antes da execução final de um aplicativo em questão, o que torna a experiência suave e sem travamentos. Entenda isso como um vídeo sendo 100% carregado antes de executado: leva mais tempo para você assistir, porém, *você assiste sem problemas*.

**Termos técnicos:**

Esse método exige **uma** requisição com o banco de dados: na hora de salvar. Essa **única** requisição não torna a sua estrutura redundante e garante o seu "tudo ou nada". Se conseguiu salvar, significa que foi tudo – e esse é um ponto no qual você levantou.

No geral, o tempo de resposta para salvar **tudo** será *menor* que o da técnica anterior. Isso porque o processamento agora é menor; o hardware responde mais rápido e consegue executar tudo com suavidade, fluidez e consequentemente mais agilidade.

A partir do momento que você não quiser mais o "tudo ou nada", considere reanalisar a técnica anterior, de streaming.